# How to define all text in the itemize level 2 be typeset in small size?

Tags: fonts, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

Is it possible to define the text of the second levels in lists of itemize- and/or enumerate-environments to be set with `\small` without having to write that command for each instance?

And it is possible to implement that definition as a switch in the document perhaps, i.e. that at one point, the `small` can be switched back to `normalsize`?

I used [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for the MWE and as far as I can tell, it strictly relates to the label of an item instance:

[image]

## Picture of MWE/Problem

[image]

## MWE

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_Us

\documentclass[
a4paper,
DIV=15,
fontsize=10pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
enumitem,
xcolor
}

\setitemize{noitemsep,nosep}%,labelindent=1em,leftmargin=1em}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textcolor{black!60!white}{$ \bullet $}}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=-,leftmargin=1.2em, font=\small}
\setlist[itemize,3]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=1.2em}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

Here are some words to form some random text.
\begin{itemize}
    \item The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    \item The following contents are written with \verb|\begin{itemize}\small|:
    \begin{itemize}\small
        \item It works, but it should automatically be typeset in \verb*|\small|, without having to define that command.
        \item Again the thing with the quick brown fox.
    \end{itemize}
    \item Another example without \verb|\small| after \verb|\begin{itemize}|in the \LaTeX{} code.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item This is not small.
            \item It is normal-sized.
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `before=\small` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works. If you post your comment as an answer, I could mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `before` key:

```
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=-,leftmargin=1.2em, before=\small}
```